# Is EXIF data stripped by iOS and/or Twitter on Tweets with images?

Tags: image, twitter, ios5, exif

I'm trying to tweet an image from an iOS5 app with code like this:

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweeter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
[tweeter addImage:image];
```

I think my EXIF is being stripped out, but not sure if it is my fault, the iOS Twitter code or the Twitter service.  I haven't found an authoritative answer yet, but [How can I get geotagged pictures posted on twitter?](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/696) seemed to point at Twitter and [Twitter photo sharing goes live for all users](http://www.digitaltrends.com/photography/twitter-photo-sharing-goes-live-for-all-users/) had this in their news story:

> Photographers will be interested to learn that all EXIF data,
>   information that identifies what equipment was used to take a picture
>   as well as the settings used, is stripped from the photos after
>   uploading

I'm trying to find an official source or better authority that my code.  I also tried to Tweet a picture from the Photos app, which also seems to have lost EXIF (location) data after upload.

Comment: I don't think you'll get an official source answer here, maybe on quora where I see some of the Twitter engineers hang out. It looks like your the resident authority on this actually.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [Twitter Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20156423-how-to-include-pictures-in-tweets):

> **What happens to the Exif data? I heard there are privacy concerns
>   there.**
>
> We remove the Exif data on upload. It is not available to any
>   consumers of your image.

Comment: I find it very concerning that the attribution data is also stripped. IANAL, but it seems to me that is a violation of copyright. In the very least that should be an account level preference defaulting to remove all.

Answer (score 5):

Just found [Social Media sites: photo metadata test results](http://www.embeddedmetadata.org/social-media-test-results.php) which tested various sites, including Facebook, Twitter and Google+.  An excerpt from their site says:

> We have uploaded a test image with embedded metadata and have checked
>   if any of the embedded values are displayed and if so, which ones. As
>   a next step we have tried to save the picture from a Social Media web
>   site or system on our computer and then we checked what metadata
>   fields are still embedded.

The Twitter test results (as of March 2013) are:

> No metadata shown, all embedded metadata stripped-off from image
>   files.